# How to store field of a Firebase document in swift variable

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm trying to access an array of references thats a field in a "post" document I have in Firebase and using the values in that array fetch posts that they reference.

However, if I call `getDocument()` on the document I'm interested in and try to return the array I get the following error. So how can I access the array and use its contents to perform other actions? Thanks!

`Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to closure result type 'Void'`

```swift
let array = usersReference.document(user.id).getDocument() { document, error in
  return document["eventsAttending"] as? [String] ?? [""]
}
```

Comment: Items stored on firebase are of type `[String : Any]`, try this instead of `[String]`

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say why this is failing without seeing your data model. When asking questions that relate to Firestore, I would recommend to also post a screenshot of one of your documents from the Firebase console.

That being said, I would recommend using Codable instead of mapping manually, as this will make your life easier.

In your case, this would look something like this:

### Model

```swift
struct Event: Codable {
  @DocumentID var id: String?
  var eventsAttending: String?
}
```

### Fetching data

```swift
func fetchEvents(documentId: String) {
  let docRef = db.collection("events").document(documentId)

  docRef.getDocument { document, error in
    if let error = error as NSError? {
      self.errorMessage = "Error getting document: \(error.localizedDescription)"
    }
    else {
      if let document = document {
        do {
          self.book = try document.data(as: Event.self)
        }
        catch {
          print(error)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Check out [this blog post](https://peterfriese.dev/posts/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/) to learn more.